# What happens with Windows applications installed via Wine during upgrades?

Tags: 10.10, 11.04, upgrade, wine

In this case I specifically want to go from 10.10 to 11.04, but maybe there are some generic descriptions out there as well. What should I expect to encounter with a program which works great under Wine right now after a version upgrade?  I understand that there is no way to say for sure, I'm just hoping to include the likely hood of results in my considerations if there is good evidence.

Will it be uninstalled, are the odds with me that it will continue to run ok, or is it more likely to end up a broken install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing happens to the Windows Apps. Wine will be the only program updated in that sense.

Comment: In fact a fairly complex windows app (as far a dependencies and such) works fine after the jump from maverick to natty.